# Avoiding JTextField setText repetition around the program

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, swing

Here is a method which displays Jobs from `SQlite` onto a table and sets them as `labelText` appropriately.

```
private void setLabelText() {
    try {

    String table_click0 = (table_job.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());        
    String sqlSt = "SELECT Employer.name, * FROM Job INNER JOIN Employer ON Job.employerID = Employer.employerID WHERE jobID='"+table_click0+"' ";
    conn = JavaConnect.ConnectDB();
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSt);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    if(rs.next()) {
        descriptionArea.setText(rs.getString(5));
        empTitLabel.setText(rs.getString(1)+" - "+rs.getString(4));
        idLabel.setText("Job Reference: " + rs.getString(2));
        typeLabel.setText("Job Type: " + rs.getString(6));
        salaryLabel.setText("Salary: " + rs.getString(7));
         benefitsLabel.setText("Benefits : " + rs.getString(8));
        vacLabel.setText("Vacancies : " + rs.getString(9));
        closeLabel.setText("Closing Date: " + rs.getString(10));
        reqLabel.setText("Requirement : " + rs.getString(11));
       placeLabel.setText("Placement : " + rs.getString(12));
       applyToLabel.setText("Apply To: " + rs.getString(13));
        statusLabel.setText("Job Status: "+rs.getString(14));
        locLabel.setText("Location: "+rs.getString(16));
         postedLabel.setText("Posted: "+rs.getString(15));        
    }
 }
```

I want to be able to now allow users to select the Job (clicked row on table) to allow editing for update of data. So i provide a form to do that, instead of repeating lines such as `descriptionArea.setText(rs.getString(5));` for Form textfields, is there a shorter way of doing this. or does each `JTextfield` have to be individually manipulated using textfieldName.setText(....) way, is there any tricks to do it shorter? any nice easy techniques to perhaps reuse the above code to minimise repetition.

Comment: Why not allow the user to edit the data within the table directly?? Or isn't there enough data in the table??  You might be able to use something like [JGoodies Binding API](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/binding/)

Comment: Using arrays generously could eliminate some of the repetitive code here. Of course, this just moves the repetitive code to initializing the arrays instead.

Comment: @MadProgrammer table gather a lot of data, so not ideal allowing editing directly, especially when one field holds description of company which is of many words.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the Apache Commons [`DbUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/), which uses [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) and [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) to simplify some of the more tedious parts of JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Despite JTextField  being for editing you could use for displaying your results. You could change to editable whenever clicked.