# Avoiding repeated `pst.setString(...)` when updating sql database with Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoiding JTextField setText repetition around the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225791/avoiding-jtextfield-settext-repetition-around-the-program)

When a form is given to user, i.e. a bunch of `JTextFields` through which they update user information, is there a way to update the database quickly instead of using repeated `pst.setString()` method, i.e.

```
  try {
                String sqlStm = "SOME UPDATE STATEMENT";
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStm);
                pst.setString(1, fieldTitle.getText());
                pst.setString(2, fieldArea.getText());
                pst.setString(3, fieldType.getSelectedItem().toString());
                pst.setString(4, fieldSalary.getText());
                pst.setString(5, fieldBenefit.getText());
            //and More here
                pst.executeUpdate();                                   
               pst.close();
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Changes Saved");
            }
```

Comment: You need some kind of bindings API, check out [JGoodies Bindings](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/binding/)

Comment: This is very new to me, can you how me an example of how to code this with a SQL statement

Comment: This looks very similar to your [previous question on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14225791/230513).

Comment: _can you how me an example of how to code_ what happened when you followed the links of @trashgod in your last question?